# base class pointer, accessing derived class member variables?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

im cutting code to make this more readable i hope i dont make this hard to understand.

```
class player : public character{
public:
    // ---------stuff-------

protected:
    // ------stuff--------
    vector <item*> inventory;
};

class item {
public:
    // -----stuff------------

    virtual float getHealth(){};
    virtual int getDef(){return 0;};
    virtual int getAttAcc(){return 0;};
    virtual int getAttPow(){return 0;};
    virtual ~item();
protected:
    string name;
    string type;
    int value;
    int weight;

};

class weapon : public item{
public:
    weapon(int attPow, int attAcc, int inValue, int inWeight, string inType, string inName);
    weapon(const weapon& cWeapon);
    int getAttAcc(weapon& weapon){return attAcc;};
    int getAttPow(){return attPow;};
    ~weapon(){};
protected:
    int attAcc;
    int attPow;
};
```

my problem comes when i need the weapon (stored with a pointer in inventory) to access its attAcc and attPow.
things i've tried:
i tried adding the virtual functions and then changing them with the derived class.

i tried leaving it out of the base class, but since the inventory is a vector of pointers to item it doesn't allow it.

originally i wanted player to have 2 pointers for weapon and armour, but because inventory is an item pointer that didnt work.

im leaving out my classes for the other items, because im sure once i figured it out for one the others are the same.  since i have 3 derived classes, i need inventory to be pointers to the base class right?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855018/c-inheritance-downcasting You need to know when and which objects you need to cast somehow.

Comment: i was looking at casting and i wasnt too sure how it would work in this case.  would it be possible to use a casted pointer to point to the item in my inventory?
what i mean is if inventory[1] is a weapon, i can use a cased point to point to it to get access?

Comment: Yes, but you need to be sure it is a weapon when you cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, what you trying to do here.

If you want to use virtual functions, it is a good thing, to use virtual keyword in the derived class as well.

But, virtual function must have same parameters (aka signature), otherwise it will just overload the base class function and virtual function mechanic will not work.

In your example, the function int weapon::getAttAcc(weapon& weapon) will not override the base class int item::getAttAcc(), because the initial function does not have a parameter.

You can add a parameter to int item::getAttAcc(weapon& weapon), if this is that you want.

Another solution could be add a type function:

```
class Item {
   public:
     virtual int getItemType() = 0; // this will make function pure virtual
};

class Weapon : public Item {
   public:
     virtual int getItemType() { return 1; }
     int getAttAcc() {return attAcc;}
}

Item * item = // something
if (item.getItemType() == 1) // weapon
{
   Weapon * weapon = (Weapon)item;
   weapon->getAttAcc();
}
```

Or, as suggested by fellow commentators. more C++ way:

```
// cast will be successful only for Weapon type object.
if (Weapon * weapon = dynamic_cast<Weapon *>(item)) { // weapon
    weapon->getAttAcc();
}
```

Comment: Just use `if (Weapon * weapon_ptr = dynami_cast<Weapon *>(item)) { weapon_ptr->getAttAcc(); }`.  It is safer and less typing than manually adding a `getItemType` function.  Your other point is correct.

Comment: Using C style casts in C++ is just bad form all around and dangerous when dealing with polymorphic types. \Use the C++ casting operators instead. in this case `dynamic_cast` is the proper method.

Comment: “But, virtual function need to have same parameters, other ways it does not count as a virtual.”  should be replaced by „But virtual functions can only be overridden by functions with the same signature.  Otherwise, it is just an *overload*.“

Comment: i tried using 5gon12eder's coding and its giving me an expected primary expression before ')'.   any idea why?  yes i corrected the dinami error

edit:  nevermind i figured it out... dumb mistake

Comment: you guys/gals are awesome thanks so much i think i have it figured out now... thanks again!

Comment: @CharlesFinley If the provided solution solved your problem you should mark it as accepted (that little check mark on the left) and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Your most immediate error is that you declared int weapon::getAttAcc(weapon&), whose signature does not match the virtual function int item::getAttAcc(). Because they don't match, you haven't overridden the function in the base class.

More fundamentally, it doesn't make sense for *class item* to be declaring functions that are meaningful only items of *class weapon*. (Unless, of course, they are meaningful. Does an item of type armour also have an attPow and an attAcc?)

That is, don't make getAttAcc (which I assume is short for "get attack accuracy") a virtual function of *class item* unless every item can be used for attack.

Instead, while looking through your inventory, if you have something you want to do only for weapons, check the type using dynamic_cast. For example:

```
class weapon : public item {
public:
    int getAttAcc() { return attAcc; };
    ...
}


item *anItem = ...;

if (weapon* aWeapon = dynamic_cast<weapon*> (anItem)) {
    ... do something with aWeapon->getAttAcc() ...
    ... and/or with aWeapon->getAttPow() ...
    }
```