# Abstract template class and inheritance contructor

Tags: c++, templates

i have problem with constructor  i want do something like this:

```
A<int>* first = new B<int>
A<int> *second;

second= new B<int>(*A);
```

I have tried use in argument list pointer,reference and value and nothing work, and i cant tell why. This is my not working constructor :

```
template <class T>
B<T>::B(B<T> other)
```

it works with `const A<T>&` thanks,
One more thing if i can. I must get access in this constructor to B class private class fields. And if i have only other which is A class. Can i do this in some other may?

Comment: How are `A<T>` and `B<T>` related ?

Comment: That code doesn't compile.

Comment: A class is base class to B. It is public inheritance

Comment: By the way: `new B<int>` is missing a `;` and `B<T> other` should be `const B<T>& other`.

Comment: Still :
 error C2664: 'B<T>::B(B<T> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'A<T>' to 'B<T> &'

Comment: Does `B<T>` have a constructor taking a `const A<T>&` ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `B<T>` inherits `A<T>`, as you described in a comment, you are trying to [downcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855018/c-inheritance-downcasting) when you write `new B<int>( some_value_of_type_A );`

You have to supply a constructor that takes type `A<T>`, like this:

```
template<class T>
B<T>::B(const A<T>& other);
```

Comment: Yes, and `second= new B<int>(*A);` doesn't mean anything because A is a type and not an object...

Comment: It started working, thank you. One more thing if i can. 
I must get access in this constructor to B class private class fields. And if i have only other which is A class. Can i do this in some other may?

Comment: @Hangoverflow You don't know if the `A<T> other` actually holds a valid `B<T>` at runtime. To find out if it does, you can use RTTI, google it.

Comment: I know because i have in tests that this is B<T> class like i write you this in first code in this question. I must get whatever it B<T> class holding in class field : value.

Comment: @Hangoverflow If you want to assume that `other` is a `B<T>`, you can cast. Either using `const B& b = static_cast<const B&>(other);` or `dynamic_cast` instead of `static_cast`. You should read up on the difference between the two.

Comment: Almost <T> :
const B<T>& b = dynamic_cast<const B<T>&>(other);

Besides that everything is perfect, thank you very much. You save my life ;d